# In the far future, when the sky is devoid of stars, will a sufficiently advanced civilization be able to discover the big bang

Tags: stellar-evolution

In the far future, when most of the stars have expanded away and the only ones visible in the observable universe are those in the host galaxy, will there be any obvious clues (assuming there are no written records) that the universe started with a big bang, or that the sky used to be filled with stars from other galaxies?

In my mind I'm thinking of a version of "soil sediments" that will contain traces of cosmic rays, etc - that could only be formed by X amount of stars in a night sky. Perhaps this would only exist on certain planets with sufficient location to be protected from normal weathering, etc

Comment: Not necessarily an answer but Isaac Asimov had fun with it in this short story: https://youtu.be/ojEq-tTjcc0

Comment: Oh nice, I'll check it out

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'have expanded away'? Remember when we look into space we also look back in time, so there will always be young stars and galaxies at the edge of the observable universe, although whether your future civilization has the technology to detect them is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have to wait for the sky to be empty of stars to find fossils of the big bang. the cosmic microwave background is detectable now and indicates a hot big bang 13 billion years ago. The cosmic ratio of hydrogen to helium, which can also be estimated observationally right now, is another fossil of the big bang.

Comment: Will background radiation always be detectable? If space expands so much, then could photon density become so low it's undetectable?

Comment: When the sky is "devoid of stars", at what redshift will the CMB be at? The He/H ratio is found from looking at "primordial", metal-poor galaxies. There wouldn't be any of those either.